# Reading a two dimensional string using gets

Tags: c, string

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char str[100][100];
    int n, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        gets(str[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);
}
```

Why i'm unable to read the string properly?

```
raja@raja-Inspiron-N5110:~/myctry$ ./a.out
2     
abc def

abc def
```

Comment: I think you are not printing that is the problem, add a loop to print also

Comment: What exactly does "properly" mean? Are you not seeing the strings in a debugger? Does your code crash?

Comment: We need more info, does your code blow up or is output not being displayed

Comment: the output is as follows                                                                            2                                                                                     abc def                                                                               im not able to read the second string

Comment: Could you edit your question to put the output in there. Then you can format it as a code block and it is clearer.

Comment: @RajaNarayan have you stepped through your code?

Comment: i have edited the code this is what i get!

Comment: Are you trying to print `abc` and `def` on two different lines? As in one string being `abc` and another `def`?

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: For example i have to read two strings say one is "stack overflow" and the other is "c program" and print these two . But with reference to above code i'm able to read only 1 string and 1 string gets printed. Why is this so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

to

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

if you press enter to input your number. this form gets rid of the '\n' in str[1] when scanf().

Answer (score 2):

You're using 1-based indexing. C uses 0-based indexing.

Change the `for` loop to `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

Comment: It would be good to note that his conditional is `i<=n` so it **would** be logically equivalent if he made the index into the array `i-1`

Comment: But the array indexing is not - he could do `str[i-1]` as well, but in his original code, `str[0]` will never be modified.

Comment: And it out of array bounds, since final i=100, while array bounds [0, 100), if n = 100

Comment: @kvv assuming `n` is entered as `100` - it could be any other integer

Answer (score 2):

Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead.

MAN

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. You need to start your for loop at index 0.
2. You should print your string out

---

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char str[100][100];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // start at i = 0
        gets(str[i]); // store string to str[0]
    printf("%s\n", str[0]); // print the results

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `gets`, assuming it doesn't overflow, end with `'\0'`? Or are you talking about the overflow case?

Comment: for(i=0;i<=n;i++) and if i input n=2 then it should be able to read 3 strings right? but i'm able to read only two strings

Comment: Are you sure you had `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)` instead of `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`?

Comment: How to use scanf() for this , because i should be able to read space also?

Answer (score 0):

Start loop from index `0` - you have started from 1

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

Moreover, you should print the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char str[100][100];
    scanf("%d", &n);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {gets(str[i]);}

         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {printf("%s\n",str[i]); }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As 7-isnotbad said,gets() is not safe,fgets() is a better choice.

Both gets() and fgets() read a line end by '\n' from buffer.

maybe you can try this code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_LINE 1024
#define MAX_ROW  100
int main()
{
    char  str[MAX_ROW][MAX_LINE];
    int i,n;
    printf("input the row of lines :\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    if(n < 1)
    {printf("input error!\n");return -1;}
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fgets(str[i],MAX_LINE - 1,stdin);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fputs(str[i],stdout);
    return 0;
}
```